# Constructing a root system from defining the angle between the roots

Tags: lie-algebras, inner-products, root-systems

Let $\mathbb{E} \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector space with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. A subset $R \subset \mathbb{E} \setminus \{0\}$ is called a root system, if $R$ has the following properties

1. $R$ is finite and spans $\mathbb{E}$
2. if $\alpha \in R$ then $-\alpha \in R$ and $\pm \alpha$ are the only multiples of $\alpha$ in $R$
3. R is invariant under the reflection in the hyperplane orthogonal to any $\alpha \in R$, i.e, $\forall_{\alpha, \beta} \in R, \; s_\alpha(\beta) = \beta - 2\operatorname{proj}_\alpha(\beta) \in R$
4. $\forall \alpha, \beta \in R, \; 2 \cdot \frac{\langle\beta, \alpha\rangle}{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle} \in \mathbb{Z}$

I am reading from [this](http://home.lu.lv/~sd20008/papers/essays/Root%20Systems%20%5Bpaper%5D.pdf) see page 2

Let $\mathbb{E} \cong \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Say $\alpha,\beta \in R$. Note the projection of $\beta$ onto $\alpha$ is $\frac{1}{2}n_{\beta \alpha}\cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and we require this number to be an integer.

In the paper they say defining what $\theta$ is constructs the root system. Say $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$. So the angle between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$. But in $R$, if we say $\beta = -\alpha$, the angle between $-\alpha$ and $\alpha$ is $\pi$, not $\frac{\pi}{3}$. So no two roots in $R$ have the angle between them $\frac{\pi}{3}$. So how does defining what $\theta$ is define the root system?

Is it that the angle between any two adjacent vectors in $R$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$? If so, that works I think.

I appreciate any clarification anyone can give.

Comment: You have to look first for the rank. For rank $1$, only $\pi/2$ works, with root system $A_1$. For rank $2$, we have several possibilities.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Okay, I think what I am confused about is what we mean by setting $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$ in rank $2$ system. Does that mean any two roots have angle $\frac{\pi}{3}$ between them, which is false, or do mean the angle between any two adjacent roots is $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: The base then is $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ for rank $2$. Then the angle between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be $\pi/4$, or $\pi/3$, or ....

Comment: Is it not clear from page 3 of the paper you link to? There they go through the options for $\theta$ and show to what root system each of them leads. Different $\theta$'s give different root systems.